# Create natural disaster model in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am working on a application where, I would like to make a 3D terrain model of my country in unity3D in clusive of hills, mountains and rivers. So far I've been able to use mapbox to import the country map because unity wrld sdk doesn't yet support my country.

However the end goal is to create an application capable of representing natural disasters. Example, I have the country. I would like to know how would one go about causing rain to occurred that would essentially affect the "water levels"  of the river and essentially show a flood. Basically, after I bring in the terrain how do I "act" on it to cause a landslide.

Any help or tutorial pointing to such would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need different models for each natural disaster. You will always only get a rough estimate of what may happen as your data will never represent the actual terrain. (For example earthquake, you may be able to reproduce damage to structures but never be able to predict if there will be a drift in the earth itself)

Rain/ Flood

A really simple simulation of rising ground water is slowly moving a "water" plane up. This crude approach will demonstrate which areas are going to be under water quite easily. For a detailed flood simulation you will need a fluid simulation of any kind (there are quite a few on the asset store)

Avalanche

Treat it as a fluid system with a strong resistance.

Vulcan

Almost the same as a flood, just with more viscosity.

Earthquake

You may be able to simulate the damage of an earthquake if all your objects have some kind of break point and the earthquake is added force to an area. A set force has an certain chance to destroy the object in the area. (Think of it in terms like any castle destroy game aka Flappy Bird, the bullet is your local earthquake and the castle your terrain + building/ trees)

Fire

You will need something like a burn value. Higher value = the longer it burns, harder to put out, faster spread. If a fire starts at any given point, it grows around. A river would have a value of 0, same as mountains. A forest would have a high value, a grass plain a low value. If you want to simulate a hot dry summer, your terrain could add a fixed value to everything, grass gets drying and thus has a higher chance to spread fire.

Comment: Thanks. But if I input a height map or map from mapbox into unity as I have and it shows up as a mesh. How can I interact with said mesh to simulate a landslide or earthquake

Comment: @Niana you can search the asset store for free examples of similar effects, https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8228 for example is for mesh deformation/ fragmentation. It may not be the best (have not tested it) but there are a lot similar free/ payed ones. You will find a lot what will be helpful for a start. Good luck.